# How do I interact with mobs after changing game mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem, whenever I change from creative to survival mode, it wont let me interact with mobs, I cant attack them nor feed them.

Comment: This is standard behaviour.  `/give` yourself a sword if you want to attack them.

Comment: Are you sure you can not interact? Try /give (your name) diamond_sword 1
then

Comment: What exact /gamemode commands are you using? What version of Minecraft? You SHOULD be able to attack mobs without a weapon (@MBraedley), unless you gave yourself a weakness effect (which I assume you did not do).

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach Yeah, I suppose your correct. I guess I just keep getting fed up with punching mobs.

Comment: Can you interact with the game in general (e.g. break/place blocks)? Are you using any mods?

Answer (score 1):

In creative mode the mobs are set to basically ignore you. (nobody wants a creeper messing up there creative mojo.) They will only notice you or engage with you if you touch them in some way. (note: not sure if just looking at an enderman will set him off in creative. you may have to touch them as well)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Endermen do get angry if you look at them in creative, they will come up really close and do the thing where their mouths open, but won't be able to hurt you